# trying to use AJAX to submit without refresh, fails silently

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I'm using WAMP to build a basic AJAX web app.  I want a form that, when submitted, inserts the input into a table in the database, without refreshing the page.

Here's the HTML for my form:

```
<div style="float: right;" id="submitDiv">
    <form id="submitForm" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="content"/>
        <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    <br>
    <span id="error" style="display: none; color:#F00">error</span>
    <span id="success" style="display:none; color:#0C0">success</span>
</div>
```

Javascript for performing the AJAX submission:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitForm').on('submit',function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/module/submit.php',
            data:$(this).serialize,
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000);
            },
            error:function(data){
                $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

`submit.php` for inserting the POST content:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['content']))
    {
        $content=$_POST['content'];
        $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testDb;charset=utf8','root','');
        $insertSQL="insert into submission (content) values ('".$content."')";
        $stmt=$db->prepare($insertSQL);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
?>
```

When I type some text into the input box and click submit, the "Success" span appears and fades, but the text doesn't appear in the console log; all I get is:

```
(index):21
```

The text is not inserted into the `submission` table.  I tried debugging `submit.php` by enabling the error log in `php.ini` as:

```
error_log = "c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log"
```

but no error log file is generated.

Any idea what's going wrong here?

UPDATE: There were at least two bugs: `.content.` should be `.$content.`, and $db->prepare() should be assigned to a prepared statement variable that then calls `execute()`.  I've made my changes in the code.  The remaining problem is that submitting the form takes me to `submit.php` instead of staying at `index.php`.

Comment: Did you test your submit.php with a regular HTML form post before messing with Ajax.  That's always a good idea.

Comment: @developerwjk, thanks, that's getting me in the right direction; in the line where I assigned a value to `$insertSQL`, it should be `.$content.` instead of `.content.`.  The `$db->execute();` line is throwing this error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in C:\wamp\www\module\submit.php on line 8`

Comment: ...and I've fixed that now, it should be `$stmt=$db->prepare($insertSQL);$stmt.execute()`.

Comment: Note that as far as AJAX is concerned an HTTP 2xx response is a success... If `$_POST['content']` isn't set, it will skip the insert and return a blank response with a 200 code. So my first check would be that you're actually sending the right data... Use your browser's dev tools (F12 / Ctrl-Shift-K) to check the request you're sending to the server

Comment: What happens when you include the full url to your script and not the relative path? Also dumb question but when you go to localhost/{your project}/module/submit.php does it actually load that script?

Comment: @Cameeob2003,yes, it runs the PHP for `submit.php` if I directly enter the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using PDO::prepare, then you should not be directly inserting your value.

Try

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['content']))
  {
    $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testDb;charset=utf8','root','');
    $insertSQL="INSERT INTO submission (content) VALUES (?)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($insertSQL);
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST['content']));
  }
?>
```

---

I think your issue is `$(this).serialize` should be `$(this).serialize()`. You should also add some checks (`if/else`) in both your js and php code to verify the insert worked.

Your js code could be

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitForm').on('submit',function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/module/submit.php',
            data:$(this).serialize(), // missing () on serialize()
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data != "Error") {
                   $("#success").html(data).show().fadeOut(5000);
                }
                else {
                   $("#error").html(data).show().fadeOut(5000);
                }
            },
            error:function(data){
                $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

and your php code

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['content']))
  {
    $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testDb;charset=utf8','root','');
    $insertSQL="INSERT INTO submission (content) VALUES (?)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($insertSQL);
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST['content']));
    if($stmt){
       echo "You successfully inserted the value " . $_POST['content'];
    }
    else {
       echo "Error";
    }
  }
  else {
    echo "You did not submit a value";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that.  The problem now is that when I click the "send" button, the data is successfully submitted but I get taken to `submission.php` instead of staying on `index.php`.  Isn't that supposed to be prevented by `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @sigil I'm unable to reproduce; what else do you have on your form page?

Comment: @Daedalus, I have another script that loads the table contents into a div.  Moving the `preventDefault()` above the `$.ajax` prevents the navigation to `submit.php`, but also prevents the data from getting submitted.

Comment: There is no way you are being taken to `submission.php` if your code is `<form id="submitForm" action="" ...`. Even if your form submitted traditionally it would refresh to the same page (`index.php`). Either your code sample is incorrect, or you have something else going on.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, that happened when I put the URL `/module/submit.php` in for the `action`.  But when I leave `action` blank, the data is not submitted.

Comment: Also, I implemented shuskic's suggestion of `else {echo "FAIL";}` in `submit.php`, which has revealed that the `isset()` is returning false.

Comment: I think your issue is `$(this).serialize` should be `$(this).serialize()`. I updated my answer with some examples of using some `if/else` blocks to verify the insert.

Comment: Yes!  That was it.  Thanks for helping me through this.

Answer (score 2):

Are your sure php is receiving the POST data?
I'd change your php file to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['content']) { //do stuff } else { echo "FAIL" }
```

This should be your first step to debugging.
Then I'd change

```
$(this).serialize
```

to

```
$("#submitForm").serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from problems of not using PDO correctly, your problem appears to be a simple typo:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['content']))
    {
        $content=$_POST['content'];
        $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testDb;charset=utf8','root','');
        $insertSQL="insert into submission (content) values ('".content."')";
        //        There should be a $ here to denote a variable ^
        $db->prepare($insertSQL);
        $db->execute();
    }
?>
```

Unsure why it isn't erroring out, given that is use of an undefined constant, otherwise.

Comment: I found and fixed that; I'll update the question.  See my comment on Sean's answer below for the remaining problem.